# Array is empty but showing as non-empty , javascript, angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am checking an Object in console, it is showing as having Array with 2 elements, but on expanding that object the array is shown as empty. How can this happen? Please see the screenshot[image]

Comment: notice `i` at end of console, it's being loaded asynchronously

Comment: so, what can I do here, it is breaking my logic

Comment: this doesn't break your code, what breaks you code is if you don't handle asynchronous behavior properly, you can post the relevant code, community people will definitely help you with some answer,